# Difference between FCM (Firebase cloud messaging) and GCM? Which one is better for Android push notification?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use Push notification in my app, Other things like sync with server database I had handled manually , So which is the best option to go ahead?

Also can I use GCM API keys with FCM?

Does FCM is free for unlimited number of messages?

Answer (score 13):

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

Comment: if we have FCM then whats use of com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0 . why play services library latest updates contain gcm. Can anyone answer

Answer (score 1):

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure, with new SDKs to make Cloud Messaging development easier.

Benefits of upgrading to FCM SDK include:

- Simpler client development. You no longer have to write your own registration or subscription retry logic.
- An out-of-the-box notification solution. You can use Firebase Notifications, a serverless notifications solution with a web console that lets anyone send notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase Analytics insights.

To upgrade from GCM SDKs to FCM SDKs, see the guides for migrating [Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm) apps.

If you'd like to see the differences between GCM and FCM, visit the Firebase documentation - [FAQ section](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/).

Comment: But I had already implemented the logic to send the notification for ios with my back end so can I send notification from my back end to andriod?

Comment: @Prashant You can still send notifications with your current implementation from your back-end to Android so long as your Android client app is properly migrated for FCM.

Comment: How can I send that? Does same GCM back end code will work or need to write new back end code for FCM?

Comment: if you migrate to fcm you will be getting above benefits i have mentioned.... Your GCM implemented app will still work fine

Comment: @Prashant - you can refer to the migration guide